Distribution of random variable obtained by non-invertible integral transformation of another random Variable
My question is concerned with the following scenario: Let $X$ be a (univariate if necessary) random variable with density $f_X$. I define the new random variable $Y$ as $Y = g(X)$. To derive the distribution of $Y$, I can use the density transformation theorem (see e.g. here https://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf) to find the density of $Y$ as
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) |(g^{-1})'(y)|,
\end{align}
if $g^{-1}$ is accessible. This is all fine, but what can I do if I can not determine $g^{-1}$? One particular case I am interested in is the case, where the transformation is given by this integral transformation:
\begin{align}
g(x) = \int K(x,y)dy.
\end{align}
Do you know how to deal with this problem?

I don't the think problem is possible in the most general case. A simple way to think about this is that $K(x,y)$ is the joint PDF of $x,y$ and $g(x)$ is the marginal of $x$. It is well known that one cannot recover the joint distribution from the marginal alone.
